# Modify back button behaviour in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my scenario:

- I have a number of list items such as this:

  List item
- When I click on the delete item, it goes to the controller, deletes the item from the database and redirects me back to my list of items.
- When the user presses browser "Back" button, a request once again is made to "/item/1/delete", however, I would like them to go back to where they were before the accessed the list of items.

I am wondering if there is a best practice/laravel way of solving this, that said, any useful alternatives are welcome.

Comment: When you delete the item do you redirect back using `back()` helper?

Comment: Are you using the return back()?

Comment: Yes, I redirect using redirect()->back()

Comment: redirect()->back() is so bad, especially when you made an action such as delete. Specify the full route.

Comment: I agree, maybe try:  return redirect('home/dashboard'); (example)

Comment: What is the difference between using back() and specifying the full route?

Comment: Well if you use back() you get taken to the last page you were on, if you use the full route you can take the user to that page also you can add ->withInput() so you could add a session message

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#redirects

Comment: Is your `delete` action a `GET` request? I.e. could I navigate to `/item/1/delete` and delete any record I want?

Comment: @TimLewis Yes, it is a get request

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use

```
return redirect('home/dashboard');
```

This way you can ensure the suer will go back without posting the form.
Also you can add more things like a session message to pop up (i.e Profile Updated)

```
return redirect('home/dashboard')->withMessage(['msg', 'The Message']);
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/responses#redirects

Comment: Yes, I tried this, but my problem is that if I press Back again after the redirect, it will again make the previous request i.e. attempts to delete the item as per my previous example.

Comment: So i assume your coming from like an edit page or something, instead of redirecting them back to the /delete page, redirect them back to the edit page. As you are doing a POST request in your routes yes it will keep posting that controller form, you need to redirect it back to a GET route.